# Is it safe to use "/bin/busybox" as path to the static usermode helper binary?

Tags: busybox, user-mode-linux

I have one question:

Can I use `/bin/busybox` as path to the static user mode helper binary, or is that a security risk?

Default is `/sbin/usermode-helper` ([CONFIG_STATIC_USERMODEHELPER_PATH: Path to the static usermode helper binary](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/STATIC_USERMODEHELPER_PATH.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Security does not really enter into it.  It just plain will not fully work.

The first argument to the usermode helper is the absolute path of an external executable program image file to run.  The first argument to `busybox` is the name of a built-in busybox command to run (from which a directory prefix is removed).

Only two of the programs that a usermode helper is expected to run (`mdev` and `modprobe`) even exist as built-in commands in BusyBox.  The others do not.

Ironically, the situation is reversed for ToyBox, which has `reboot` and `poweroff` built-in commands but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

No, `busybox` is an (very) optional add-on in Unix/Linux systems, it's version used could very well be locally built (and thus residing in `/usr/local`) or even built by the user running it (perhaps in `$HOME/bin`, or somewhere exotic under the account). Safest bet is a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env busybox`, with instructions to just run the script directly as `busybox funky-script` (or edit it to local customs) if `./funky-script` fails.